# ImportError: cannot import name 'log' from 'webdriver_manager.logger'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-import, libraries

I have been trying to mess around with some Selenium stuff in PyCharm, and I have come across the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'log' from 'webdriver_manager.logger'
```

Which is a result of the copied code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

However the error comes up in the package, from the line of code:

```
from webdriver_manager.logger import log
```

From looking online it seems that this is because there is another name that clashes with it? But in all honesty I have no idea why its messing up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you install the right module? https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Comment: @DSteman I'm pretty sure I have, as the import itself works, plus I followed all of the correct links

Comment: Can you post the last line of the error trace?

Answer (score 0):

the webdriver_manager package in not install correctly, so you just need to uninstall and reinstall webdriver_manager package.
the list of webdriver_manager are:
webdriver-manager
py-webdriver-manager

### for more certainly:
scrapy-webdriver

after that, your issues will be solved